# Can some one help me parametrize $\frac{x^4}{a^4}+\frac{y^4}{b^4}+\frac{z^4}{c^4}=1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

Given a surface $$\frac{x^4}{a^4}+\frac{y^4}{b^4}+\frac{z^4}{c^4}=1$$how can I parametrize the surface using $X(u,v).$

I tried to use $$x=a\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)}$$ $$y=b\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)}$$ $$z=c\sqrt{\sin(\phi)}$$ but turns out it couldn't include all the points of the surface. Can some help me solve it? (The problem is that maybe we need to think about how to parametrize $x^4+y^4=1?$)

Comment: Have you tried using signed square root instead of square root? $$\text{signed_root}(x) = \text{sign}(x)\sqrt{|x|} $$
Also, I think the last one is wrong. Shouldn't it be $cos\phi$ instead of $sin\phi$?

Comment: A recent [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227629/a-question-about-how-to-parametrize-a-surface-in-r3) question with the same idea at a solution (but no accepted answer, so perhaps isn't technically a duplicate), and a [strongly overlapping](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204622/how-to-show-that-x-y-z-in-mathbbr3x4y4z4-1-is-diffeomorphic-to) but technically non-identical question whose accepted answer gives a strategy that also answers this question. (Numerous similar examples can be found on Math.SE by searching for "diffeomorphic to sphere".)

Answer (score 0):

First let $r = x^2/a^2$, $s = y^2/b^2$, $t = z^2/c^2$.  Then you have sphere in $(r,s,t)$.  parameterization of the sphere can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html).

Comment: It's not an ellipsoid. $x^4,y^4,z^4$ are used here, not $x^2,y^2,z^2$.

Comment: Your'e right, it is a sphere.

Comment: It's not a sphere in Euclidean space. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^4%2By^4%3D1) is how it looks like.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. A sphere in $(r,s,t)$ would involve negative values of each co-ordinate, but that doesn't happen here.

Comment: Stop complaining about minor issues: the $(r,s,t)$ parametrization obviously gives a *part* of a sphere - the one living in the first octant.